# MYSQL - Group by name and include the according values of other columns in the results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Firstly, I would like to apologise if the title is misleading.

I have a table in `mysql` named **products**:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+
| name    | price | date      | brand |
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+
| apples  | 2     | 02/12/17  | Tesco |
| apples  | 1.95  | 28/11/17  | Aldi  |
| apples  | 2.5   | 29/11/17  | Lidl  |
| bananas | 0.5   | 01/12/17  | Tesco |
| bananas | 0.7   | 29/11/17  | Aldi  |
| bananas | 1     | 25/11/17  | Lidl  |
+---------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

If I wish to `SELECT` the `MAX` price from this table, I would go ahead and execute this query:

```
SELECT
  products.name AS NAME,
  MAX(products.price) AS MAX_PRICE
FROM products
GROUP BY products.name;
```

Which would output:

```
+---------+-----------+
| NAME    | MAX_PRICE |
+---------+-----------+
| apples  | 2.5       |
| bananas | 1         |
+---------+-----------+
```

However, I would also like to include the respective date and brand in my query output like this:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| NAME    | MAX_PRICE | DATE     | BRAND |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| apples  | 2.5       | 29/11/17 | Lidl  |
| bananas | 1         | 25/11/17 | Lidl  |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

The same would do for `MIN` in the `SELECT` statement:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| NAME    | MAX_PRICE | DATE     | BRAND |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
| apples  | 1.95      | 28/11/17 | Aldi  |
| bananas | 0.5       | 01/12/17 | Tesco |
+---------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

How can this be written in `MySQL`?

Comment: This is a common question See the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for many past questions with solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it by myself but if you will add max to the date, and add it in the group clause something like this -

```
SELECT
  products.name AS NAME,
  MAX(products.price),MAX(products.date)  AS MAX_date,BRAND 
FROM products

GROUP BY products.name,products.date,BRAND ;
```

Answer (score 0):

mySQL has non-standard feature that makes these queries simpler than standard SQL:

```
  SELECT
  name AS NAME,
  MAX(products.price) AS MAX_PRICE, date, brand
  FROM products
  GROUP BY name;
```

it will randomly choose one tuple from the subset from which to grab date and brand.
If there is a functional dependency from {name, price} to {date, brand}
this is equivalent to adding date and brand to the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Do this without `group by`.  Here is one way:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.price = (select max(p2.price) from products p2 where p2.name = p.name);
```

Not only is this correct, but it can take advantage of an index on `products(name, price)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join with the result to pick up the other rows in result.

```
SELECT p.name AS NAME,p.price AS MAX_PRICE, p.date as DATE, p.brand as BRAND 
FROM products p JOIN 
(
    SELECT brand, max(price) as brand_max_price 
    FROM products p
    GROUP BY brand
) t 
ON p.brand = t.brand AND p.price = t.brand_max_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your own query by adding a join to the same table again.

```
SELECT Z.NAME, Z.MAX_PRICE, A.DATE, A.BRAND
FROM
products A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT products.name AS NAME,  MAX(products.price) AS MAX_PRICE
FROM products
GROUP BY products.name) Z
ON A.NAME = Z.NAME AND A.price = Z.MAX_PRICE;
```